# Android - android-gpuimage-plus video resolution issue

Tags: android, opengl-es, video-processing, gpuimage, android-camera2

I am using this library to apply the filter on video recording the filters are working fine but The recorded video is looking a stretched, Please see the image of the recorded video.
anyone can guide me how to fix this issue?

https://github.com/wysaid/android-gpuimage-plus - library

recorded video image
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/2811593/44643358-dd4db200-a9ed-11e8-9f60-096f85668122.png

Comment: have you tried to [open an issue](https://github.com/wysaid/android-gpuimage-plus/issues/new) on GitHub?

Comment: @Alex, I have already posted on github.
https://github.com/wysaid/android-gpuimage-plus/issues/355

Comment: I would be helpful if you also disclose the preview size chosen on your device.

Comment: 480 x 640 (by default in the demo)

Comment: The video is definitely not **480x640**. See where the [recording size is chosen](https://github.com/wysaid/android-gpuimage-plus/blob/master/library/src/main/java/org/wysaid/view/CameraGLSurfaceView.java#L140) and log the actual *(width, height)* that you get. See also what actual [preview size](https://github.com/wysaid/android-gpuimage-plus/blob/master/library/src/main/java/org/wysaid/camera/CameraInstance.java#L286) was set for camera. I believe that CameraInstance.initCamera() should do better job choosing the camera sizes.